# Error in initializing vector of lists

Tags: c++, list, vector, initialization

Here is my code:

```
...
using namespace std;
class QueryProcessor {
int bucket_count;

vector<list<string> > hash_row(bucket_count);

size_t hash_func(const string& s) const {
    static const size_t multiplier = 263;
    static const size_t prime = 1000000007;
    unsigned long long hash = 0;
    for (int i = static_cast<int> (s.size()) - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        hash = (hash * multiplier + s[i]) % prime;
    return hash % bucket_count;
}

public:
explicit QueryProcessor(int bucket_count): bucket_count(bucket_count) {}
...
```

and this error occurs: [Error] 'bucket_count' is not a type.
What's wrong with my declaration?

Answer (score 1):

> What's wrong with my declaration?

You cannot declare and initialize a member variable like that.

You can declare it as:

```
vector<list<string> > hash_row;
```

and initialize the member in the constructor using:

```
explicit QueryProcessor(int bucket_count): bucket_count(bucket_count),
                                           hash_row(bucket_count) {}
```

Comment: But when I put it out of any classes, like this:

Comment: But when I put it out of any classes, like this:
using namespace std;
int main(){
 int n;
 vector<list<int> > hash(n);
 cin >> n;
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
  hash[0].push_front(i);
 for(list<int>::iterator i = hash[0].begin(); i != hash[0].end(); i++){
  cout << *i << " ";
 }
 return 0;
}
It works correctly!

Comment: That works because you are not declaring and initializing a member variable of a class. You are declaring and initializing a function local variable.